# how to create object type in c++ like object type in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, object, code-conversion

I wanna create various objects like this in c++ and use them as function parameters. Is it possible?
How can I do that ?

```js
example = {
   "name": "example_name",
   "values" : [{"key": "value"},{"key": "value"}, ...]
   "more_info": {"address": "some_text", "city": "some_city", ...},
};

example2 = {
   "code": "some_code",
   "attributes": [...],
   "creation_date" : "some_date",
};

some_func({"use_atribute": false, "send_message": true, "first_val": example, "second_val":  example2});
```

Comment: Not without a lot of effort. C++ is a strongly typed language and JavaScript is weakly typed.

Comment: You can get quit close to javascript objects witth a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (or  [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) with [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) as values.